# Can I discover the state of a tableview gesture recognizer in a tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom tableviewcell in my table cell what I am trying to do is when the user pans left to right in the cell the cell handles that gesture and scrolling in the tableview is disabled. I have that bit working but if the user starts scrolling first and pans left to right whilst scrolling the pan still happens.

I want to set a bool that says the parent is scrolling so don't pan, I can make that work as I can detect the scroll in

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

as the otherGestureRecognizer will be a UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer and gestureRecognizer will be UIPanGestureRecognizer.

My issue is how do I determine when the UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer has ended in the table cell because if I set a flag I'll need to unset it when the scroll ends so that if the user wants to pan after the scroll they can.

I hope that all makes some kind of sense if not ask me for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this one. I have implemented a custom gesture recognizer which fails if the first movement is up or down as it indicates a scroll. If the first movement is left or right it succeed and prevents the scroll.

If anyone is interested I'll post the code.